swap curve calibration with interpolation using newton-like method
suppose 2 swap market quotes for 1Y and 2Y and that swap payments occur semi-annually.
calibrating / obtaining the discount factors means finding 4 unknowns / discount factors that reproduce the market quotes such that
$$
\textrm{min } f = \sum_{i=1}^2 \epsilon_i \\
\textrm{ with } \epsilon_i = (mktQuote_i - modelQuote_i)^2 \\
\textrm{ and modelQuote}_i := floatLeg_i / fixLeg_i 
= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^N (\delta_j * fwrd_j * DF_j)}{\sum_{j=1}^N (\delta_j * DF_j)}  
$$
for j = 1, 2, ..., N payments on swap "i".
considering log-linear interpolation on the discount factors (DF) is to be used, is it possible to set up a nice Newton-like scheme, that is, $(DF_{k+1} = DF_k - J^{-1}(DF_k) * f(DF_k))$, with the Jacobian a square matrix, to solve this problem ?
References / articles / books that discuss this topic ?

You cannot solve for 4 degrees of freedom with two fixed parameters. That is an underspecified curve and it will (even though solvable, with infinite solutions) lead to chaotic behaviour within your solver.
In your case, however, you are adding hyper parameters, in the form of interpolation, so that 2 of the discount factors are implied, via interpolation from the other 3 (the first discount factor at the start of your curve is fixed at 1.0).
Yes, it is possible to setup a newton like solver. The one below solves for two parameters with two instruments.
# PYTHON
from rateslib import *

curve = Curve(
    nodes={  # initialise 3 discount factors
        dt(2024, 5, 22): 1.0,
        dt(2025, 5, 22): 1.0,
        dt(2026, 5, 27): 1.0,
    },
    calendar="nyc",
    interpolation="log_linear"
)

solver = Solver(
    curves=[curve],
    instruments=[
        IRS(dt(2024, 5, 24), "1y", frequency="S", spec="usd_irs", curves=curve),
        IRS(dt(2024, 5, 24), "2y", frequency="S", spec="usd_irs", curves=curve),
    ],
    s=[5.16, 4.76],
    algorithm="gauss_newton"
)
SUCCESS: `func_tol` reached after 3 iterations (gauss_newton), `f_val`: 4.139106658800514e-14, `time`: 0.0023s

Relevant intermediate discount factors would then be known:
curve[dt(2024, 11, 24)]  # 0.974328
curve[dt(2025, 11, 24)]  # 0.927691

As well as those that have parametrised your curve:
curve.nodes
# {datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 22, 0, 0): 1.000000,
#  datetime.datetime(2025, 5, 22, 0, 0): 0.950244,
#  datetime.datetime(2026, 5, 27, 0, 0): 0.905908}

You can read more about this Solver at https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c_solver.html
The books I have personally written on this are "Coding Interest Rates: FX, Swaps and Bonds" which just documents algorithms used in rateslib, and "Pricing and Trading Interest Rate Derivatives: A Practical Guide to Swaps" which is broader and contains more generalist info related to swaps trading. (https://www.amazon.com/Pricing-Trading-Interest-Rate-Derivatives-dp-0995455546/dp/0995455546/ref=dp_ob_title_bk)
Edit
Solver gradients are available. The API docs are at https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rateslib.solver.Gradients.html#rateslib.solver.Gradients although these don't make a huge amount of sense without the deriving documents.
The key gradients you are requesting are:
solver.grad_v_rT  # alias of solver.J
# array([[-103.8040534 ,   -2.38011349],
#       [  -1.45812049,  -54.08994059]])

solver.grad_s_vT
# array([[-0.00963949,  0.00042417],
#       [ 0.00025986, -0.01849916]])

The former is used in the calibration part where sensitivities to the rates determine by how much to adjust the discount factors.
The latter is used in risk sensitivities when you want to measure the economic sensitivity of a portfolio to the movement in the rates of instruments. The automatic differentiation returns sensitivities to discount factors and these have to be transformed to sensitivities to instruments rates. I.e
$$
\nabla_\mathbf{s} P = \nabla_\mathbf{s} \mathbf{v^T} \nabla_\mathbf{v} P
$$

hadn't realised you were the author. been consulting your practical guide (an older version) for quite some time.


from the documentation, the first argument to the irs method should be the effective date, correct ? if so, shouldn't the 2Y IRS be effective as of dt(2024, 5, 25) instead of dt(2025, 5, 25) ?


is it possible to output the matrix of first derivatives from the Solver ? i understand the delta() method uses it (here -> https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/j_delta.html). i'd be interested in consulting the supplmentary material documenting it, if available / possible.



yes just a mistype in stack. Although it shows you can still price the curve even with  mistaken instruments that happen to still be appropriate. Yes all the Solver gradients are available. See edit.

ok thanks. just to clarify a few elements: is the quantity $\nabla_s v^T$ obtained through the inverse function theorem applied to $\nabla_v r^T$ ? does rateSetLib render the portfolio sensitivity to DFs ($\nabla_v P$) ? i understand this is calculated at the same time as P through AAD, correct ?

yes, yes and yes.
